# Android SQLite, how can I get the records of the last two days?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I work on android monitoring application and I have to display the data record during the last two days, how do i proceed?

The type of the date table is **TEXT**

**CODE OF MY SQLITE TABLE trafic**

```
    private static final String tableTrafic ="CREATE TABLE "+ 
    TraficEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ( "
                +TraficEntry.COL_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT 
    , "
                +TraficEntry.COL_IN + " DOUBLE  , "
                +TraficEntry.COL_OUT + " DOUBLE  , "
                +TraficEntry.COL_STARTIME + " TEXT  , "
                +TraficEntry.COL_ENDTIME + " TEXT  "

                +"); ";
```

Comment: what are the values for start_time and end_time are they dates stored in string?

Comment: Yes, these are stock dates in `YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM: SS.SSS` format, but for the moment I have not entered the database yet!

Comment: Better you enter date-time in timemillis.

Comment: You need to at least show us some concrete sample data if you want an answer here.  Please don't ask us to speculate about both your table and the data.

Comment: What does "the last two days" mean? A start time 48 hours or less from the current time?

Comment: It means _A start time at 48 hours_